# Running minitest produces no output

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have a file `my_test.rb` with the following contents:

```
require 'test/unit'

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  # Called before every test method runs. Can be used
  # to set up fixture information.
  def setup
    # Do nothing
  end

  # Called after every test method runs. Can be used to tear
  # down fixture information.

  def teardown
    # Do nothing
  end

  # Fake test
  def dummy_test
    print "Something!"
    fail
  end
end
```

When I run `ruby my_test.rb`, there is absolutely no output.

How can I run the unit tests in this file and see whether they are passing or failing?

Comment: Note that [minitest](https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest) and [test-unit](https://rubygems.org/gems/test-unit) are different testing libraries. Your code is using test-unit but your title says minitest.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing bad with your implementation and your actual code. But in order your `dummy_test` can execute what's inside its definition, it should be called first; thing you're not doing, that's why when you run your file you don't get any output.

You can create an example test, and there call your dummy_test method:

```
...

def test_something
  dummy_test
end

# Fake test
def dummy_test
  print "Something!"
  fail
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Test-unit will look for methods that *start* with “test” and use them as test methods. Your code has a method that *ends* with “test” but none that start with it, so it doesn’t see any tests to run.

Change the method name from `dummy_test` to `test_dummy` and you should see the output you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

As said before you are not calling on your function and therefore nothing will happen since ruby does not automatically execute the first / last function.

An example would be to implement this code

```
...
def main()
    print "Something!"
end

main()
```

And if you would like to call a function which calls the other functions you will do the same

Example:

```
def main()
    other_function1()
    other_function2()
end

main()
```

And the other_functions would be other functions you define and call within the main function.